# Cosmos DB SQL API - How to query a field name that uses a reserved word

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to query a collection for some documents where one of the fields happens to be named 'top'. However, I can't directly reference this column in a select statement because the name conflicts with the TOP keyword. For example:

```
SELECT C.code, C.top FROM c
```

This throws the following error - "Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'top'."

Is there anything I can do to escape this field name, or will I have to rename the field to something else?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**top** is a reserved keyword. To escape this use **`[""]`** syntax.

```
SELECT  c.code,c["top"] FROM c
```